# How to get the last selected radio button using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

May I ask if there's any way to capture the last selected radio button in AngularJS?

For instance, I have the following code that renders four radio buttons:

```
<li ng-repeat="query in carousel.currentQuestionObject.choices" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
        <input class="TWInputField" 
               name="{{carousel.currentQuestionObject.name}}" 
               type="{{carousel.currentQuestionObject.inputType}}" 
               id="{{query.id}}"
               ng-model="carousel.checkboxCollection[query.id]" 
               ng-value="{{carousel.currentQuestionObject.value}}">

        <label for="{{query.id}}" 
               style="font-family:'MetricWeb-Regular';
                      font-size:17px;cursor:pointer">&nbsp;&nbsp;
               {{query.question}}
        </label>
```

I first selected radio #3, but then changed my mind and selected radio #4 instead. Then I clicked the Next button in this page.

```
<div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" 
     ng-click="carousel.wizardNext(carousel.checkboxCollection)" 
     ng-hide="carousel.currentQuestionIndex == carousel.wizardQuestionSet.length - 1">
     Next
</div>
```

My problem is, after inspecting the checkboxCollection, I saw that values for radio buttons 3 and 4 are both true, even though I only selected #4. Is there any way I can tell my program that #3's value is already false?

For your reference, here's what I tried to do (which didn't work...):

```
vm.wizardNext = function(obj) {
    try {
            for (var i = 0; i < idxCnt; i++) {
                vm.checkboxCollection[i] = obj[i];
            }           
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    // other code here
}
```

Am I missing something here? How should I go about this?

[image]

Hoping for your inputs. Thank you.

Comment: share your code in online compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround after stumbling across this question: [How to uncheck a radio button to make all objects become false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700425/in-angularjs-how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button-to-make-all-objects-become-false). So I revised my code as follows. Hopefully this can help others who'll have a similar problem:

Array containing questions:

```
{ inputType: "radio", name: 'qs1needs', question: "Tell us about your needs...", 
  choices: [
            { question: "I'm currently...", id: "qs1q1", selected:false },
            { question: "I'm currently...", id: "qs1q2", selected:false },
            { question: "I want to...", id: "qs1q3", selected:false },
            { question: "I want to...", id: "qs1q4", selected:false }
]}
```

HTML:

- changed value of ng-model
- added ng-change, value and ng-value

  ```
  <input class="TWInputField" name="{{carousel.currentQuestionObject.name}}" 
         type="{{carousel.currentQuestionObject.inputType}}" id="{{query.id}}" 
         ng-model="query.selected" 
         ng-change="carousel.changeOnSelection(query.selected, query.id)"
         value="" ng-value="true">
  ```

AngularJS:

```
// Check values of radio buttons on change
    vm.changeOnSelection = function(selectedValue, selectedID) {

        // item refers to each item inside choices 
        angular.forEach(vm.currentQuestionObject.choices, function(item) {  
            /* since answer is already bound to model, 
               if selected ID is not equal to ID in focus, change value to false.
            */
            if (item.id !== selectedID) {                                       
                item.selected = false;
            }           

        });
    }
```